# How to find a constant term in CDF

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose I'm given a CDF: $Cf(x)$ for $x<0$ and 1 for $x\ge 0$. I need to find $C$. What is my strategy? I don't know calculus very well, unfortunately. So far I only have the following solution:

1. Find the derivative
2. Take an integral with the limits from $-\infty$ to $0$ and make it equal $1$.
3. Find $C$

But I am not sure whether I'm right because it's weird to take a derivative and put it into an integral assuming that I already know the antiderivative. As you see, I'm totally confused.

Comment: Hint: What is $f(0)$?  What is $\mathbb P(X \le 0)$? What is $Cf(0)$?

Comment: @Henry
I got confused, I'm afraid. $Cf(x) = P(X \le 0)$, right?

Comment: As @Henry has pointed out, you want to find the value for $C$ such that $Cf(0)=1$. No need for all the fancy calculus stuff.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson But what if $f(x)$ does not exist in $0$?

Comment: @alekscooper Without seeing $f$ its hard for me to know. Is this a CDF for a continuous random variable? If so, you may need to take a limit. But again, without seeing $f$ it will be hard for me to say definitively.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson something like $C*\dfrac{\ln\left(1-x\right)}{x}$

Comment: @alekscooper Ah yes you definitely [need a limit](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+log%281-x%29%2Fx+as+x-%3E0+from+below). To derive the limit yourself you need L'Hopitals rule.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Thank you!

Comment: Good luck to you in your academic career, study your differential and integral calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cumulative distribution function $F$, we have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}F(x)=1$$

So indeed, if the variable is absolutely continuous, then

$$\int_\mathbb R f(x)dx=1,$$

where $f$ is the derivative of $F$. Hence if you have $f_2=Cf$, then

$$\int_\mathbb R f_2(x)dx=C \Rightarrow f=\frac{f_2}{C}.$$

In this case we have
$$F(0)=1\Leftrightarrow CF(0)=C,$$

so all you need to do is evaluate $CF(0)$, which is possibly

$$CF(0)=C\int_\mathbb {R_{\leq 0}} f(x)dx$$.

Comment: In the OP's question $F(x)=Cf(x)$ (not standard notation which was a bit confusing). The problem was to determine the normalizing constant $C$ so that $F(0)=1$.